# Dynamics F&O - Cannot import XML for new sales order

Tags: xml, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-operations

While using an XML file import I'm running into a validation error:

> Error executing code: The field with ID '0' does not exist in table 'SalesOrderLineStaging'.

It looks like the XML file is going into staging:

[image]

The header is fine. No errors:

But then the line is erring out:

[image]

There are no references to a sales order number in the XML:

Sales orders composite V2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <SalesOrderHeaderV2Entity>
    <SALESORDERNUMBER/>
    <AREPRICESINCLUDINGSALESTAX>0</AREPRICESINCLUDINGSALESTAX>
    <ARETOTALSCALCULATED>0</ARETOTALSCALCULATED>
    <CUSTOMERPOSTINGPROFILEID>GEN</CUSTOMERPOSTINGPROFILEID>
    <CUSTOMERTRANSACTIONSETTLEMENTTYPE>1</CUSTOMERTRANSACTIONSETTLEMENTTYPE>
    <DEFAULTLEDGERDIMENSIONDISPLAYVALUE>001--</DEFAULTLEDGERDIMENSIONDISPLAYVALUE>
    <DELIVERYADDRESSCOUNTRYREGIONID>USA</DELIVERYADDRESSCOUNTRYREGIONID>
    <DELIVERYADDRESSDESCRIPTION>Endor</DELIVERYADDRESSDESCRIPTION>
    <DELIVERYADDRESSNAME>Contoso Europe</DELIVERYADDRESSNAME>
    <DELIVERYADDRESSTIMEZONE>0</DELIVERYADDRESSTIMEZONE>
    <DELIVERYMODECODE>40</DELIVERYMODECODE>
    <DELIVERYTERMSCODE>FOB</DELIVERYTERMSCODE>
    <EMAIL>contoso.europe@vendor8.consolidatedmessenger.com</EMAIL>
    <FIXEDDUEDATE>1900-01-01T00:00:00-05:00</FIXEDDUEDATE>
    <FIXEDEXCHANGERATE>0.0000000000000000</FIXEDEXCHANGERATE>
    <INVENTORYRESERVATIONMETHOD>0</INVENTORYRESERVATIONMETHOD>
    <INVOICECUSTOMERACCOUNTNUMBER>US-003</INVOICECUSTOMERACCOUNTNUMBER>
    <ISDELIVERYADDRESSORDERSPECIFIC>0</ISDELIVERYADDRESSORDERSPECIFIC>
    <ISDELIVERYADDRESSPRIVATE>0</ISDELIVERYADDRESSPRIVATE>
    <ISEINVOICEDIMENSIONACCOUNTCODESPECIFIEDPERLINE>0</ISEINVOICEDIMENSIONACCOUNTCODESPECIFIEDPERLINE>
    <ISENTRYCERTIFICATEREQUIRED>0</ISENTRYCERTIFICATEREQUIRED>
    <ISONETIMECUSTOMER>0</ISONETIMECUSTOMER>
    <ISOWNENTRYCERTIFICATEISSUED>0</ISOWNENTRYCERTIFICATEISSUED>
    <ISSALESPROCESSINGSTOPPED>0</ISSALESPROCESSINGSTOPPED>
    <LANGUAGEID>en-us</LANGUAGEID>
    <ORDERINGCUSTOMERACCOUNTNUMBER>US-003</ORDERINGCUSTOMERACCOUNTNUMBER>
    <PAYMENTTERMSBASEDATE>1900-01-01T00:00:00-05:00</PAYMENTTERMSBASEDATE>
    <PAYMENTTERMSNAME>Net10</PAYMENTTERMSNAME>
    <PRICECUSTOMERGROUPCODE>09</PRICECUSTOMERGROUPCODE>
    <REQUESTEDRECEIPTDATE>2018-11-30T00:00:00-05:00</REQUESTEDRECEIPTDATE>
    <REQUESTEDSHIPPINGDATE>2018-11-30T00:00:00-05:00</REQUESTEDSHIPPINGDATE>
    <SALESORDERNAME>Farts</SALESORDERNAME>
    <SALESORDERORIGINCODE>PHONE</SALESORDERORIGINCODE>
    <SALESORDERPOOLID>01</SALESORDERPOOLID>
    <SALESORDERPROCESSINGSTATUS>5</SALESORDERPROCESSINGSTATUS>
    <SALESORDERPROMISINGMETHOD>0</SALESORDERPROMISINGMETHOD>
    <SALESTAXGROUPCODE>EXMPT FOR</SALESTAXGROUPCODE>
    <TAXEXEMPTNUMBER>998765</TAXEXEMPTNUMBER>
    <TOTALDISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>0.000000</TOTALDISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>
    <TRANSPORTATIONDOCUMENTLINEID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</TRANSPORTATIONDOCUMENTLINEID>
    <WILLAUTOMATICINVENTORYRESERVATIONCONSIDERBATCHATTRIBUTES>0</WILLAUTOMATICINVENTORYRESERVATIONCONSIDERBATCHATTRIBUTES>
    <SalesOrderLineEntity>
      <SALESORDERNUMBER/>
      <ALLOWEDOVERDELIVERYPERCENTAGE>0.000000</ALLOWEDOVERDELIVERYPERCENTAGE>
      <ALLOWEDUNDERDELIVERYPERCENTAGE>0.000000</ALLOWEDUNDERDELIVERYPERCENTAGE>
      <CUSTOMERSLINENUMBER>0</CUSTOMERSLINENUMBER>
      <DEFAULTLEDGERDIMENSIONDISPLAYVALUE>001--</DEFAULTLEDGERDIMENSIONDISPLAYVALUE>
      <DELIVERYADDRESSCOUNTRYREGIONID>USA</DELIVERYADDRESSCOUNTRYREGIONID>
      <DELIVERYADDRESSNAME>Contoso Europe</DELIVERYADDRESSNAME>
      <DELIVERYADDRESSTIMEZONE>0</DELIVERYADDRESSTIMEZONE>
      <DELIVERYMODECODE>40</DELIVERYMODECODE>
      <FIXEDPRICECHARGES>0.000000</FIXEDPRICECHARGES>
      <INVENTORYRESERVATIONMETHOD>0</INVENTORYRESERVATIONMETHOD>
      <ISDELIVERYADDRESSORDERSPECIFIC>0</ISDELIVERYADDRESSORDERSPECIFIC>
      <ISDELIVERYADDRESSPRIVATE>0</ISDELIVERYADDRESSPRIVATE>
      <ISINTRASTATTRIANGULARDEAL>0</ISINTRASTATTRIANGULARDEAL>
      <ISLINESTOPPED>0</ISLINESTOPPED>
      <ITEMNUMBER>D0001</ITEMNUMBER>
      <LINEDESCRIPTION>Mid-Range Speaker</LINEDESCRIPTION>
      <MULTILINEDISCOUNTAMOUNT>0.000000</MULTILINEDISCOUNTAMOUNT>
      <MULTILINEDISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>0.000000</MULTILINEDISCOUNTPERCENTAGE>
      <ORDEREDSALESQUANTITY>1</ORDEREDSALESQUANTITY>
      <REQUESTEDRECEIPTDATE>2018-11-30T00:00:00-05:00</REQUESTEDRECEIPTDATE>
      <REQUESTEDSHIPPINGDATE>2018-11-30T00:00:00-05:00</REQUESTEDSHIPPINGDATE>
      <SALESORDERPROMISINGMETHOD>0</SALESORDERPROMISINGMETHOD>
      <SALESPRICEQUANTITY>1.000000</SALESPRICEQUANTITY>
      <SALESPRODUCTCATEGORYNAME>Speakers</SALESPRODUCTCATEGORYNAME>
      <SALESTAXGROUPCODE>EXMPT FOR</SALESTAXGROUPCODE>
      <SALESTAXITEMGROUPCODE>AU/VI</SALESTAXITEMGROUPCODE>
      <SALESUNITSYMBOL>ea</SALESUNITSYMBOL>
    </SalesOrderLineEntity>
  </SalesOrderHeaderV2Entity>
</Document>
```

In the mappings I have set SALESORDERNUMBER in the header to auto-generate.

I also set SALESORDERNUMBER in the line item for auto default.

Comment: Try to perform restart AOS, DB sync, CIL compilation. If it doesn't help please provide more details about your customization

Comment: @AliaksandrMaksimau This is a Contosso environment. I'm able to put in an order through the web interface without issues. I have no idea what AOS and CIL is. AOS? Is that the web service?

Comment: My suggestion will be try importing sales header and lines separately to make sure if data is getting imported without error. <SalesOrderNumber/> field is required in line entity then and not required in composite xml.

Comment: You probably just need to compile everything again. `Id '0'` sounds to me like it's trying to reference something it's not aware of because it's not fully compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is related to DMF, and also there's a new field in the table that you are trying to import.

I'm not fully experienced with D365, but at least in 2012 there's an issue where the configuration doesn't fully update new custom fields, my suggestion if that's the case you should recreate the configuration anew and try again with this one.